# How can I update a Swing canvas at a certain framerate?

Tags: java, scala, swing

So for a school project i have to make a game in Scala with Swing

I have started by making a window, with a button, and a canvas on which i can draw everything i want.

The problem is that the only way i found to update my canvas is event-based, for example when i press a button

I would like to be able to refresh the canvas at a certain framerate, but it seems that swing is event based, and i don't know where i could put a while loop, or something like this to have a constant update rate

Comment: FWIW: Swing timers are also event generators.

Comment: Anyway, if not using a library to already handle the details, I would probably use double-buffering with the generation done on a background thread and then flip-to-active. There are plenty of examples: see “swing canvas game fps” or similar searches.

Comment: Since this question is not SPECIFICALLY about Scala (excepting syntax implementation or friendly libraries), I’ve also added Java which may pick up more related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a loop that repeatedly calls `repaint()`.

Note that calling `repaint()` will only putting out a request and return immediately (before painting), so you can't really control the framerate, you can just limit it.

To measure the framerate, you need to calculate the time difference between now and the last paint cycle in the `paintComponent()` function of your canvas.

I recently answered a similar question, you can copy the code from there, if that is applicable for scala (I don't really know the language):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60110451/5784265